# Probability of hitting the target for the nth time on the mth throw

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, binomial-distribution

**A boy is throwing stones at a target. Probability of him hitting the target is $\frac{1}{2}$ . Then the probability of him hitting the target for the  5th time in 10 throws is ?**

```
The answer given is 1/2 .
```

Now ,the reason given is that no matter how many throws he takes or no matter how many times he hits (be it 10 times in 10 throws or 6 times in 7 throws or all initial 5 throws hitting the target out of 10 throws ) since the probability of him hitting the target is always **1/2** therefore the net probability will always be 1/2.

But while putting it into the binomial distribution formula the answer coming is different.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably each throw is *independent* of one another (*something which is critical to note in order to continue the problem because without this assumption there is not enough information to answer*).

Now... the event we are interested in calculating the probability of as I understand your question to be is that among the first nine throws, exactly four of the throws were hits and also the tenth throw is a hit.

The results of the first nine throws is going to be independent of the result of the tenth throw, so we can find the probabilities of each and multiply the results.  To calculate each, we can use a binomial distribution.

This gives:

$$\binom{9}{4}0.5^4\times 0.5^{9-4} ~~~\times ~~~0.5$$

Or simplified:

$$\binom{9}{4}\times 0.5^{10}=\dfrac{63}{512}$$

---

If your question is instead, what is the probability that within ten throws, at least five of the throws are hits, then this will be

$$\sum\limits_{k=5}^{10}\binom{10}{k}0.5^k\times 0.5^{10-k}$$

or simplified

$$\dfrac{319}{512}\approx 0.623$$

It is equally likely that there are strictly more hits than misses versus having strictly more misses than hits here.  It is also possible that there are an equal number of hits and misses, and so the probability that we have at least as many hits as misses (i.e. 5 or more) will be strictly more than $0.5$.

Compare this to if there are an odd number of throws, where it is no longer possible to have an equal number of hits and misses.  If we throw nine times, we find that since it is just as likely to hit as to miss, then the probability to get more hits than misses will be $0.5$ without needing to run the calculations manually.

Comment: Yes,i too had got the same answer (63/512) using the binomial distribution idea ,and it was one of the answer options given ,but not the correct one . So I don’t know what’s the missing piece .

Comment: @H0RS3 When talking about problems like these, it is critical that the exact wording of the problem is correct.  There is a big difference between the questions "given that four of the first nine throws are hits, what is the probability that the tenth throw is the fifth hit" and the question "what is the probability that the tenth throw is the fifth hit."  If you can share the *exact* original phrasing of the question or the source of the problem, then we might be able to help further, but until then the only viable interpretations of the problem in my opinion are what I discuss above.

Comment: The question source states ,”the probability of hitting the target for the 5th time in the the 10th throw is “

Answer (score 1):

In $10$th throw, the probability doesn't change. So his chances of hitting the target would still be $1/2$. It doesn't matter how many times he has hit the target before. Even if he misses the target a million times in a row, the probability at million+1 throw would still be $1/2$. Lookup [gambler's fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_fallacy).

Comment: Yes ,but before the 10th throw is made he has already successfully hit the target 4 times out of the 9 times ,and each of those had a 50% probability, so when the last throw is made ,wouldn’t the cases where the previous throws were hit at different numbered try , add on to the final case ?

Comment: But the question was not about the past throws. It was just about the 10th throw, right ?

Comment: Here I'm rephrasing your question which may be more clear:  A boy is throwing stones at a target. Probability of him hitting the target is 1/2 . It is given that boy has hit the target 4 times in 9 throws. Then the probability of him hitting the target for the 5th time during 10th throw is?

Comment: It is similar to the question: `If a coin showed 4 heads in 9 throws, whats the probability that it shows heads again in 10th throw?`

Comment: My guess is you've interpreted the question incorrectly. And of course the wording is a bit vague.

Comment: Could be due to the questions vague description but , if it would have been an independent event ie only the last throw is taken into consideration Ito would have been 1/2 , but instead it is a series of continuous events ,cumulating at the 10th throw .

Answer (score 1):

In probability theory this is called a *negative binomial distribution*. What it does is answer the question of what is the probability that you will have $n$ successes after $m$ attempts. Technically this notation is wrong, but I modified it to match your question.

For example, you could say that in the event of a Best-of-$3$ rock paper scissors game, what are the odds that the match will be over after only $2$ rounds? In your case the question is, what are the odds that he will hit the target for the $n$th time on the $m$th throw. The formula is as follows

$$
\binom{m - 1}{n - 1}p^n(1-p)^{m-n}
$$

The $\binom{m-1}{n-1}$ comes from the fact you need to choose the location of all successes, and already know that the final throw has to be a hit to make sure your condition is satisfied. So in your example with $p=\frac{1}{2}$, the formula for any $m$ and $n$ are

$$
\binom{m - 1}{n - 1}\dfrac{1}{2^m}
$$

so for $n=5,m=10$ we find

$$
\binom{9}{4}\dfrac{1}{2^{10}} = \dfrac{63}{512} \approx 12.3\%
$$

Comment: I too kinda used this logic initially, but then ,could it be that the probability of hitting the target for the 5th time on the 10th throw is (maybe) independent of whatever cases we could form for the initial 4 successful throws ,as at the end of the day , finally him hitting on target is still gonna be 50 % on the 10th throw.

Comment: Oh well yes, assuming that after $9$ throws $4$ have already been hit, then there is a $50\%$ of getting $5$ in $10$ because the events are all independent of each other. My answer is if you are trying to determine the probability before the first throw

Comment: Oh alright , taken .

Answer (score 1):

Probability of hitting target is $~\frac{1}{2}~$ and therefore probability of hitting target is $~1- \frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{2}~$.

So $~P~=~$$\{$ probability of hitting target $~4~$times in $~9~$ throw $\}~-~\{$ probability of hitting target in $~10^{th}~$ throw $~\}$

$~~~~~~~~~~=~\left\{^9C_4 ~\times~ \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^4~\times~ \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^5\right\}~\times~\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$

$~~~~~~~~~~=~^9C_4 ~\times~ \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{10}$

$~~~~~~~~~~=\frac{63}{2^9}$